# Reshaping a Tensor in TensorFlow with scalar tensors

Tags: python, reshape, tensorflow

I have a tensor, `X` of shape `(T, n, k)`.

If I knew the shape beforehand, it is easy to reshape, `tf.reshape(X, (T * n, k))` where `T, n, k` are ints, not tensors.  But is there a way to do this if I don't know the shapes.  It seems that getting the shapes like `shape = tf.shape(X)` and reshaping doesn't work.  That is,

```
tf.reshape(X, (tf.shape[0] * tf.shape[1], tf.shape[2]))
```

Any ideas?  In my application, `T` and `k` are known before runtime but `n` is only known at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([a, b, c], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
s = tf.shape(x)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
v1, v2, v3 = sess.run(s)
y = tf.reshape(x, [v1 * v2, v3])
shape = tf.shape(y)

print sess.run(y)
print sess.run(shape)
```

I am getting the shape of the variable after it's initialization and then use it later. Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33642096/1090562), as it deals with a similar thing.

Comment: While I think this would work, I''m worried that it adds overhead to the computation.  In Theano, `reshape()` accepts symbolic variables, I was wondering if there was a solution like that, maybe by concatenating the separate scalars into a new Tensor or something like this.

Comment: @AsianYayaToure this clearly works because I tested it :-). I would not worry about the overhead at this stage. Make sure that your model works as expected and predicts what you want it to predict.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. In your example, the shape of `x` is known at graph building time.  You've explicitly set `a, b, c = 2, 3, 4`.  Try this: x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [100, None, 3]) and do the same.

Comment: @AsianYayaToure I got you. You should have told that you use `tf.placeholder`. I will write a new answer, which works with placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you told that you use placeholders to populate data, it started to make sense. Here is an example of how can you reshape your data in this case:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)

x = tf.placeholder("float", None)
s = tf.shape(x)

sess = tf.Session()
shape_original = sess.run(s, feed_dict={x: data})

x_ = tf.reshape(x, [shape_original[0] * shape_original[1], shape_original[2]])
s_ = tf.shape(x_)

shape_now = sess.run(s_, feed_dict={x: data})
print 'Original\t', shape_original
print 'Now\t\t\t', shape_now

sess.close()
```