# How do I create a custom cost function using numpy in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm very new to tensorflow, and I want to define my own cost function using numpy for my project described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386026/how-do-i-create-a-school-matching-system-using-neural-networks)

This is my code I copied:

```
# Backward propagation
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=yhat))
updates = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

# Run SGD
sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(updates, feed_dict={X: train_X, y: train_y})
```

I want to change this cost function to another function I already have defined using numpy. Is there a way to convert the y tensor to a numpy array and then back to a tensor.

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=yhat))
```

I haven't had success using `transpose()` and `eval()` because it was necessary to be run during a `tf.session`.

Here is the loss function in numpy:

```
def loss_perunage(ones_array,votearray):
    results = countresults(ones_array,votearray)
    return 1 - results[0]/int(len(a))
```

The function uses another dataset to compute how good the results are.
I want this perunage be the cost.

Hope you guys can give me tips on this, feel free to ask anything if something is unclear.

Edit: Sorry for my English, I'm not native

Comment: Hello @DJosh, this question may be a duplicate of, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684441/writing-a-custom-cost-function-in-tensorflow, which is worth a read! Basically, you should be defining your own cost functions using `tensorflow` operations because NumPy isn't designed to handle `tensorflow` objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing a custom cost function in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684441/writing-a-custom-cost-function-in-tensorflow)