# How to see values inside tensor while using skflow

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I've checked [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow). However doesn't seem to be working out of the box with skflow.
E.g. tried like this :

```
with tf.Session():
    word_vectors = skflow.ops.categorical_variable(X_test[0], n_classes=n_words,embedding_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, name='words')
    word_vectors.eval()
```

Also tried

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
```

before calling word_vectors.eval(). But all this leads to crash:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/mypc/Documents/scripts/scikitflow/small_rnn_test/test_load.py", line 32, in <module>
    word_vectors.eval()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 405, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2728, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 345, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value words/words_embeddings
     [[Node: words/embedding_lookup/embedding_lookup = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](words/words_embeddings, words/embedding_lookup/Reshape)]]
Caused by op u'words/embedding_lookup/embedding_lookup', defined at:
  File "/Users/mypc/Documents/scripts/scikitflow/small_rnn_test/test_load.py", line 31, in <module>
    word_vectors = skflow.ops.categorical_variable(X_test[0], n_classes=n_words,embedding_size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, name='words')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skflow/ops/embeddings_ops.py", line 77, in categorical_variable
    return embedding_lookup(embeddings, tensor_in)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skflow/ops/embeddings_ops.py", line 50, in embedding_lookup
    embeds_flat = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids_flat, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/embedding_ops.py", line 46, in embedding_lookup
    return array_ops.gather(params[0], ids, name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 302, in gather
    name=name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 633, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Does anybody know relatively easy way to look at content of Tensors created by skflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what error you are throwing but I got the error "Attempting to use uninitialized value words/words_embeddings".  Initializing the variables fixed the error.

So the working code was:

```
word_vectors = skflow.ops.categorical_variable([1,2], n_classes=3,embedding_size=2, name='words')
with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  word_vectors.eval()
```

I have also moved the graph node `word_vectors` outside of the session context though that wasn't necessary to fix the error.

Comment: Thanks, that appeared to be the problem. Should have started with TF directly, rather than with skflow.

Answer (score 0):

`categorical_variable` won't initialize all the variables for you. It's not like the estimators that initialize the session, variables, graph, etc. At this moment, if you use `tf.initialize_all_variables().run()`, you will be able to get those values. Also, note that you can access weights and biases via `bias_` and `weights_` properties of the estimators.