# How to check the values of a Tensor object in the debug mode in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Following the code,

```
normal_rv=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,3], stddev=0.1))
init_op=tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(normal_rv))
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/37543184/1279459)

we can print the values of the tensor.
However, how can we check those values after or before the printing command at the debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to the code where we assign the output of the sess.run(normal_rv) to a new variable leads to the answer:

```
normal_rv=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,3], stddev=0.1))
init_op=tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res=sess.run(init_op)
    print(res)
```

[image]