# I want to print all variables and placeholders in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I run the sample code [recurrent_network.py](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py).

I wish print all the x, it's a placehoder. In the function: `RNN(x, weights, biases):`

What can I do?

Key point:

```python
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    # Reshaping to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow) for details.  I usually use [tf.Print()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print) myself.