# how to compare the 'int' number to a tensor[0]

Tags: tensorflow

if my tensor is [0 ,1]. I want to get "if 1==tensor[1]" is true, want should I do in tensorflow. I have tried tensor.eval() function, it work ,but is not work for all of my project.
thanks

Comment: Please add _why_ it is not working in all of your projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new tensor using `tf.Variable(1)` and compare this with the existing tensor using `tf.equal()`.
This will return a tensor of type *bool*. You can print the value of this tensor using `tensor.eval()` or `tf.Print()` { using tf.InteractiveSession() } the following way:
[How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)