# How to evaluate a Variable?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to get the value of tensor.

```
# First Layer
encoder_layer1 = tflearn.fully_connected(x,41,activation='relu',bias=True)
layer1_weights = encoder_layer1.W
layer1_bias = encoder_layer1.b
```

result of printing it out is:

```
The layer 1 weights are:   <tf.Variable 'FullyConnected/W:0' shape=(41, 41) dtype=float32_ref>
```

even eval() doesn't seem to work. it throws an error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value FullyConnected/W
     [[Node: _send_FullyConnected/W_0 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=true, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=-6055748491062458677, tensor_name="FullyConnected/W:0", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](FullyConnected/W)]]
```

I have tried all the methods metiond but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Problem has been resolved! Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly:

You can't evaluate any tensor variable outside of session, you must do it inside a `session`,

Why can't:

In order to understand why we can't do this, at first we should now what's going on the behind of tensorflow, since every thing in tensorflow is a node of graph, when we define variables and assign values to them, actually we are designing the graph and values are not assigned until we run the graph.

How to run graph:

Session executes the graph, consider the code blocks when we design a network in tensorflow, everything before session like blueprint and after this `tf.session as sess` line, like construction site, so you can only evaluate (`eval()`) tensors inside session. In the other words, graph defines operations, and operations only execute inside a session.

Hope this was useful. For more, read [this](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/hello-tensorflow)

Comment: I have a session in my trainer function and I am running the eval() in 'with trainer.session.as_default()', its then I get the second error

Comment: @WiLL_K the error states clearly: you first have to initialize the variable

Comment: I had initialized the variables before hand, I have the problem solved, it was just that tflean and tensorflow were unable to recognize the with `trainer.session.as_default()`, I had to declare the session inside of the `eval(session=trainer.session)`. Problem is solved. I think i have messed up when I was building it with some more instruction set.

Comment: Thanks @dv3 and Ali Abbasi