# Formatting tf.Tensor data into numpy.ndarray

Tags: tensorflow

I need to display the results of the tensorflow simple net prediction (a histogram of the network predictions), say, for example, for the [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) code.

The problem is I can't display results of the prediction in a readable format for this purpose (numpy.ndarray would be ideal). Predictions 'y' come up as `<tf.Tensor 'Softmax_3:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>` and so far I haven't found a way of changing this format.

If anyone knows how to do that could you please advise me on that?

I've tried `np.array(y)` (still keeps the Tensor format inside of the array  and `y = tf.Variable([y], expected_shape = [55000,10])`( throws an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expected_shape'`).

If this is of interest the code looks like that:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

for _ in range(1000):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run the session with target variable to get it in python array. (as same as train_step and accuracy). 
Do this :

```
pred_np = sess.run(y,feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})
```

Now, pred_np is a numpy array. You can print/save/display it. Hope this helps.