# shapes are incompatible error in CNN model using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm try to make a convolutional network for roof top classification with two classes 0,1.

The images size are 128x128, I use 3 more convolutional layer to reduce it to 6 x 5 as adviced here

I'm very new at convolutional network. So, I may be wrong in some place, so feel free to advice me on this.

```
def cnn_model_fn(features,labels,mode):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1,128,128,3])

    #Convolution layer #1
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input_layer,filters=28,kernel_size=[5,5],padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu)

    #Pooling layer #1
    pool1=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

    #Convolution layer #2
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1,filters=14,kernel_size=[5,5],padding="same",activation=tf.nn.relu)

    #Pooling layer #2
    pool2=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,pool_size=[2,2],strides=2)

    # Dense Layer
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 128 * 128 * 3])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dense2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense, units=64, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dense3 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense2, units=32, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense3, rate=0.4, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    # Logits Layer
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)

    loss = None
    train_op = None

    # Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
    if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=4)
        loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    # Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=0.001,
        optimizer="SGD")

    # Generate Predictions
    predictions = {
      "classes": tf.argmax(
          input=logits, axis=1),
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(
          logits, name="softmax_tensor")
      }
```

> #Image data into train and test

```
data_dir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/exzeo/Category1/' 
data_dir2='C:/Users/user/Desktop/exzeo/Category2/'
data_images=[]
data_labels=[]
for image_path in glob.glob(data_dir+"*.png"):
    data_images.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_path),(128,128)))
    data_labels.append(np.array(0))
for image_path1 in glob.glob(data_dir2+"*.png"):
    data_images.append(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_path1),(128,128)))
    data_labels.append(np.array(1))
data=np.float32(np.asarray(data_images))
labels=np.float32(np.asarray(data_labels))
train_data, eval_data, train_labels, eval_labels = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

> Model Fitting

```
def main(unused_argv):
    building_classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn)
    #     # Set up logging for predictions
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)
    building_classifier.fit(x=train_data,y=train_labels,batch_size=128,steps=10000,monitors=[logging_hook])
    #     # Configure the accuracy metric for evaluation
    metrics = {"accuracy":learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),}
    eval_results = building_classifier.evaluate(x=eval_data, y=eval_labels, metrics=metrics)
    print(eval_results)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        tf.app.run()
```

As, it throw me a error as `ValueError: Shapes (?, 2) and (?, 4) are incompatible`

Comment: Could you give us a hint of where the `ValueError` occurred (which line in your code above)?

Comment: @MPA hi, it occured in this line: building_classifier.fit(x=train_data,y=train_labels,batch_size=128,steps=10000,monitors=[logging_hook])

Comment: Should `tf.one_hot` not have a `depth` of 2?

Comment: @MPA for depth=2 also it doesn't work. Gives: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: Well, given that you got a different error, I suppose you now got past the line with `tf.one_hot`. What is the value of `loss` at the line with `tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss`?

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Just so you know: adding comments like yours above will not bump this question back to the top of the page, like on a forum board. I suspect that the `NoneType` comes from the `loss` variable (see my comment above), but as long as you don't verify this, there isn't anything we can/will do to help.

Comment: @MPA how do I check it? Initially I assign it as 'None' you can check in code itself

Comment: Print it to screen: [*How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633839/1510542)

Comment: @MPA yeah I have reslove the error issue. now its showing error as :Input to reshape is a tensor with 501760 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 49152. is there something wrong in parameters of dense layers.?

Comment: This is now turning into an interactive debugging session, for which SO is not the right place. You should check your layer inputs and outputs, make sure you have the right `stride`, and follow the instructions that you get from the program output. This is not something we can easily help you with.