# How to convert string tensor (obtained from .tfrecords) to float tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The input to my network comes from files containing int32's. They are stored as .tfrecords as follows:

```
  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
      'data': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[data])) }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

I then read the tfrecords file like so:

```
with tf.name_scope(self.name):
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([path])
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={ 'data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string) })

  data = features['data']
```

After reading tfrecords I have string tensors like this:

```
Tensor("X/ParseSingleExample/ParseSingleExample:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

I would like to first convert this to int32's as that is what the initial data represents. After that I need to end up with a tensor of floats, can someone point me in the right direction?

PS Im new to tensorflow, please let me know if I can provide more useful information

Comment: Are you reading tfrecords as a part of input pipeline, with `tf.parse_single_example` or you just want to examine it with `tf.python_io` api? Please add your code so that we could help you

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You may consider the option of storing the data directly as a vector of floats instead of reinterpreting it every time on load. As the answer points out, [`decode_raw`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_raw) should help, just make sure the `little_endian` parameter is correct.

Comment: yeah the data flow is not optimal atm, baby steps ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help

```
data = features['data']
decoded = tf.decode_raw(data, tf.int32)
```

This will output tensor of dtype `tf.int32`. Then you can reshape it and cast to `tf.float32`

```
decoded = tf.reshape(decoded, shape)
decoded = tf.cast(decoded, tf.float32)
```

If you want inspect contents of a tfrecords file outside `tf.Session`

```
for str_rec in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('file.tfrecords'):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(str_rec)
    data_str = example.features.feature['data'].bytes_list.value[0])
    decoded = np.fromstring(data_str, dtype)
```

To verify the content of a tensor you can inject a print node in the graph as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296783/175592)

```
# Add print operation
decoded = tf.Print(decoded, [decoded])
```

Comment: thanks for this, it appears to work. Btw can I inspect the actual values somehow? Using tf 1.7.1 atm

Comment: Updated question, this will do if you don't have a session

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, I was referring to the contents of the float tensor