# How to check values of Keras tensor using 'backend.print_tensor'?

Tags: python, keras

I want to check some values of my Keras tensor. I tried to use `backend.print_tensor`.

I have changed my package code of Keras, and I changed the code `tf.Print` -> `tf.print`.

```
x = Dozat(21)(x) # custom Lambda layer

x = backend.print_tensor(x)

print('x : ', x, '\n\n\n')
```

This message occurred.

> WARNING:
>   Print (from tensorflow.python.ops.logging_ops) is deprecated and will be removed after 2018-08-20.
>   Instructions for updating:
>   Use tf.print instead of tf.Print. Note that tf.print returns a no-output operator that directly prints the output. Outside of defuns or eager mode, this operator will not be executed unless it is directly specified in session.run or used as a control dependency for other operators. This is only a concern in graph mode. Below is an example of how to ensure tf.print executes in graph mode:

```py
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    tensor = tf.range(10)
    print_op = tf.print(tensor)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
      out = tf.add(tensor, tensor)
    sess.run(out)
```

Comment: The title is wrong. 'backend.tensor_print' -> 'backend.print_tensor'

Comment: My version : keras : 2.2.4 tensorflow : 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `out` is defined inside a with block, but you are trying to run it outside of the block in which it is defined. Try indenting your `sess.run(out)` to where it is valid.

```
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    tensor = tf.range(10)
    print_op = tf.print(tensor)
    with tf.control_dependencies([print_op]):
      out = tf.add(tensor, tensor)
      sess.run(out)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment :). I appreciate your favor. I tried your way, and it works. The answer is goot, but that is not a exact answer that I want. I have a question. How do you usually do when you wanna check the value of your own tensor or layer's output?? Thanks.

Comment: @JKD_Spiegel Perhaps the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633839/11496617) is what you are looking for?