# How to fix flatlined accuracy and NaN loss in tensorflow image classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am currently experimenting with TensorFlow and machine learning, and as a challenge, I decided to try and code a machine learning software, on the Kaggle website, that can analyze brain MRI scans and predict if a tumour exists or not. I did so with the code below and began training the model. However, the text that showed up during training showed that none of the loss values (training or validation) had proper values and that the accuracies flatlined, or fluctuated between two numbers (the same numbers each time).

I have looked at other posts but was unable to find anything that gave me tips. I changed my loss function (from sparse_categorical_crossentropy to binary_crossentropy). But none of these changed the values.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import os


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from random import shuffle

IMG_SIZE = 50

data_path = "../input/brain_tumor_dataset"
data = []
folders = os.listdir(data_path)
for folder in folders:
    for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_path, folder)):
        if file.endswith("jpg") or file.endswith("jpeg") or file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("JPG"):
            data.append(os.path.join(data_path, folder, file))

shuffle(data)
images = []
labels = []
for file in data:
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    images.append(img)
    if "Y" in file:
        labels.append(1)
    else:
        labels.append(0)

union_list = list(zip(images, labels))
shuffle(union_list)
images, labels = zip(*union_list)
images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)

train_img = images[:200]
train_lbl = labels[:200]

val_img = images[200:]
val_lbl = labels[200:]


train_img = np.array(train_img)
val_img = np.array(val_img)
train_img = train_img.astype("float32") / 255.0
val_img = val_img.astype("float32") / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=2),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=2),

    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.8),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



history = model.fit(train_img, train_lbl, epochs = 100, validation_data=(val_img, val_lbl))
```

This should give a result with increasing accuracy, and decreasing loss, but the loss is nan, and the accuracy is flatlined.

Comment: The dataset can be found on https://www.kaggle.com/navoneel/brain-mri-images-for-brain-tumor-detection

Comment: Also, now that I look at it, some stuff like import numpy is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. I looked at my code again and realized that my output layer only had one node. However, it needed to output the probabilities for two different categories ('yes' or 'no' for whether it is a tumour or not). Once I changed it to 2 nodes, the network began working properly and reached 95% accuracy on both the training and validation sets.
My validation accuracy still fluctuates a little between a few values, but this is most likely because I only have 23 images in the validation set. In order to decrease the fluctuations, however, I also decreased the epoch number to just 10. Everything seems to be great now.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the cause of the flatlining accuracy is the NaN loss. I'd try to figure out at what point in the computation the loss is becoming NaN (in inference? in the optimiser? in the loss calculation?). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow) details some methods for outputting these intermediate values.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how I would use those. Could you maybe repost with a code example?

Comment: Ah sorry, I just realised you were using Keras. This might not be a good answer, since you don't have direct access to the tf tensors.