# Using tensorflwo2.0, how should I check the value of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have many tensors now but I found that I can only print out shapes and data types using the print method. Is there any way I can view their values? I am learning tensorflow2.0

```
# the version is tensorflow2.0
SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("DeserializeSparse_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64))
Tensor("DecodeJpeg:0", shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: What about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Comment: No, it's not.Still can't get the specific value