# Loss function testing

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I just want to define a loss function to test.

I used as example the euclidean distance:

```
def euc_dist_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1, keepdims=True))
```

Since I have to obtain from the net list of couples (x,y), I want to test this outside the NN.

So I used:

```
y_true = [[0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
y_pred = [[1., 1.], [1., 0.]]
```

With just:

```
edk = euc_dist_keras(y_true, y_pred)
```

I obtained the error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

So I used:

```
y_true_array = np.array(y_true)
y_pred_array = np.array(y_pred)
edk = euc_dist_keras(y_true_array, y_pred_array)
```

But obtained:

```
Tensor("Sqrt:0", shape=(2, 1), dtype=float64)
```

Instead of expected output value: 1

How to obtain the desired value?
The same euc_dist_keras, used in:

```
model.compile(loss=euc_dist_keras, optimizer=opt)
```

will work exactly in the same way I'm testing it?

Thanks!

---

Added:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:  print(edk.eval())
```

I obtained:
[[1.]
[1.]]

I expected:
1.

Maybe I make some mistake in the def?
Or the mean of all samples is made just when I use it when compile the model?

Comment: you need to add K.mean in the loss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is TensorFlow v1 code. If so, you must run the operations within a "session" in order to evaluate them. See SO post [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow) and the TF v1 documentation on sessions:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session

Comment: In each case: with tf.Session() as sess:  print(edk.eval()) seems to almost work. It gives [[1.][1.]]. I expected 1.