# Inspect value of a tensor in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I struggle to apply answers to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow), with Tensorflow 2.6.0.

I would like to inspect the values in my tensor during debugging. If I do a Python print

```
predicted_ids=tf.random.categorical(predicted_logits, num_samples=1)
predicted_ids=tf.squeeze(predicted_ids, axis=-1)
print(predicted_ids)
```

I get

```
Tensor("Squeeze:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int64)
```

I then try to

(1)

```
print(tf.Print(predicted_ids, [predicted_ids], message="This is predicted_ids: "))
```

(2)

```
with tf.Session() as sess:  print(predicted_ids.eval())
```

(3)

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
a = tf.Print(predicted_ids, [predicted_ids], message="This is predicted_ids: ")
```

All of which will throw errors. It seems to me this is a very common question, and there must be an elegant robust simple answer, in TF 2.6.0.

Comment: @hafiz031 already gave you the answer. Use the `numpy` **method** (not attribute) as he showed.

Comment: error is obtained with `predicted_ids.numpy()` unfortunately

Comment: Something must be off either with `predicted_logits` or your installation because I tried the code above  with `[0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4]` in lieu of `predicted_logits` and `.numpy()` worked fine on TF 2.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly simple:

For example:

`tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5, 0.5]]), 5).numpy()`

Output:

`array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1]])`

[image: numpy()]

In your case:

`predicted_ids.numpy()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to create a session as .eval() function is compatible with TensorFlow v1.
The code which works for me fine is to use tf.print() function. Here's a quick demo:

```
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
d = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
e = tf.matmul(c, d)
print(tf.print(e))
```

Comment: this prints something ugly `name: "PrintV2"
op: "PrintV2"
input: "StringFormat"
attr {
  key: "end"
  value {
    s: "\n"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "output_stream"
  value {
    s: "stderr"
  }
}`