# See the tensor values after tf.unstack

Tags: tensorflow

Returning a tensor value with command

```
    a, b, c, d, e = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
```

then when I try to display the value of `a` all I get is:

```
<tf.Tensor 'unstack_4:0' shape=(5,) dtype=int32>
```

How can I see which are the values of this tensor?

I'm pretty new to TensorFlow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print the value of a Tensor object in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

In TensorFlow 2, you can use `tf.backend.eval()` to evaluate a tensor that is outside of a `tf.function` if it hasn't yet been evaluated (more on that in the next section).

```py
a, b, c, d, e = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
print(tf.keras.backend.eval(a))
```

---

> How is it that is not possible to just type `a` and see your tensor value?

You likely not have `Eager Execution` enabled. The significance of this delves a bit into the inner workings of TensorFlow.

In TensorFlow there are two modes of execution, [`Eager Execution`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) and [`Graph Execution`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs).

##### Eager Execution

In `Eager Execution`, operations like `tf.unstack` are evaluated immediately and return concrete values. This is the usual behavior you would expect from python and is the default mode of execution in TensorFlow 2 outside of [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function) and functions like [`tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/disable_eager_execution).

In `Eager Execution`, passing `a` into the interpreter would indeed return a concrete value.

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> # Create a 5x5 matrix
>>> x = tf.constant([[i for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)])
# A bunch of messages regarding compute devices appear as TensorFlow initializes its backend to evaluate the expression immediately
>>> a, b, c, d, e = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>
```

##### Graph Execution

With `Graph Execution`, every time you input an operation like `tf.add(a, b)` or `tf.unstack`, these operations are added to a [TensorFlow graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph) rather than being immediately executed. By building the graph first and deferring execution, Tensorflow can improve the performance of the computations by [optimizing](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_optimization) the built graph.

Because of this, with a statement like `a, b, c, d, e = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)`, `a` prints the TensorFlow operation rather than an output value.

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> # Here we disable eager execution
>>> tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
>>> # Create a 5x5 matrix as before. Notice the lack of messages
>>> x = tf.constant([[i for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)])
>>> a, b, c, d, e = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'unstack:0' shape=(5,) dtype=int32>

>>> # Evaluate the graph and store it in result
>>> result = tf.keras.backend.eval(a)
>>> result
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
>>> # `a` still refers to an operation if you were wondering
>>> a
<tf.Tensor 'unstack:0' shape=(5,) dtype=int32>
```

Comment: this is what I get by tf.print(a) : <tf.Operation 'PrintV2_2' type=PrintV2> so I still cannot see my tensor value. How is it that is not possible to just type 'a' and see your tensor value?

Comment: I should have spotted that your tensors aren't `EagerTensors`. `tf.print()` will only print the values if you have eager execution enabled. I will update the answer accordingly.